# Dynamic Scalable Mysql Table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, nosql

Here is my situation. I used Python, Django and MySQL for a web development.

I have several tables for form posting, whose fields may change dynamically. Here is an example.

Like a table called `Article`, it has three fields now, called `id INT`, `title VARCHAR(50)`, `author VARCHAR(20)`, and it should be able store some other values dynamically in the future, like `source VARCHAR(100)` or something else.

How can I implement this gracefully? Is MySQL be able to handle it? Anyway, I don't want to give up MySQL totally, for that I'm not really familiar with NoSQL databases, and it may be risky to change technique plan in the process of development.

Any ideas welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can i know why you need to create fields dynamicallly

Comment: @suhail Er… I did this for an organization, and they have really dynamic demands on some user post forms.

Comment: This is a really bad idea

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, but it seems no other way out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [this post](http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql) about FriendFeed's schemaless SQL approach.

Loosely:

- Store documents in JSON, extracting the ID as a column but no other columns
- Create new tables for any indexes you require
- Populate the indexes via code

There are several drawbacks to this approach, such as indexes not necessarily reflecting the actual data. You'll also need to hack up django's ORM pretty heavily. Depending on your requirements you might be able to keep some of your fields as pure DB columns and store others as JSON?

Comment: I'm thinking about that these days, too. Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually used it, but [django-not-eav](http://django-not-eav.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) looks like the tool for the job.

"This app attempts the impossible: implement a bad idea the right way." I already love it :)

That said, this question sounds like a "rethink your approach" situation, for sure. But yes, sometimes that is simply not an option...

Comment: It seems the project is no longer hosted in GitHub or PyPi, and I cannot find the source code...

Comment: I found another version of it, but when I run it, it gives an `Database Error`, which says `no such column: relationfields_foreignkeymodel.related_to_id`. I tried with Django1.4 and Django1.5, which lead to the same result, have u ever tried this?